# Implementing Macro in a Rascal language project

Tags: rascal

Any idea on how to implement macro syntax with Rascal and also how to implement the typing and expansion(translation) of the macro syntax in Rascal? Any link to projects or repositories on this problem would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Macro's are definitions of code substitutions in syntax trees, which is definitely one of the main features of Rascal. Questions I would have before advicing specific techniques:

1. adding macro's to an existing languages, or to a new language?
2. macro's at refactoring time, at compile-time  or a run-time?
3. which would inform the question whether or not to implement macro's on concrete syntaxt trees or abstract syntax trees.

I would not say macros are a "problem" per se. The raw substitutions in syntax trees are trivial with Rascal. However, "hygienic macros" are more involved. Here we have to consider the capturing of variables by the expanded macro bodies, and what we can do about this (renaming) to avoid it. The literature on how to make macros hygienic is plenty. The complexity of hygienic macros depends on the type and name analysis (scoping) system of the base language that macros are added to.

If you have a DSL that you want to translate in stages to the target code, that can also be called "macros", but you will not find that name in the documentation. Here is an example: https://github.com/usethesource/flybytes/blob/main/src/lang/flybytes/macros/ControlFlow.rsc where "macro" is used to rewrite an additional AST node to its semantics in the "core" language.

The basic mechanisms are:

- pattern matching: detects what you want to expand, with macros this is often a single ADT constructor but it can also be a more complex special case like matching `i+=1` to substitute it with `i++` .
- substitution: at the location where the match was found, we create a new AST value in a simpler language but with the same semantics. This is done with AST expressions in Rascal, the `=>` operator in `visit` and `insert` statements, and `return` and `=` in functions.
- traversal: guiding the pattern matching and substitution without having to write to much boilerplate recursive functions.

Small example:

```
data Bool(loc src=|unknown:///|) 
    = \and(Bool l, Bool r) 
    | \or(Bool r, Bool r)
    | \true()
    | \false()
    | \not(Bool a)
    ;
```

I extend the language with a "macro":

```
data Bool = impl(Bool l, Bool r)
```

A first option is to rewrite the constructor immediately and always with an overloaded function:

```
Bool impl(Bool l, Bool r) = or(not(l), r);
```

However, we lose some information here for debugging purposes, so let's try to keep the information intact:

```
Bool impl(Bool l, Bool r, src=loc s) = or(not(l), r, src=s);
```

Sometimes we want to delay the expansion for a specific stage in the compiler. In particular with the above "rewrite rule" a type-checker will not see the different anymore between `==>` and `||` which sometimes creates usability issues with error messages.

In that case we wrap the expansion in a `visit` and stage it as a function:

```
Bool macroExpansion(Bool input) = visit(input) {
    case impl(Bool l, Bool r, src=loc s) => or(not(l), r, src=s)
    // add more rules here
}
```

It is also possible to encapsulate rewrite rules as reusable functions:

```
Bool expand1(impl(Bool l, Bool r, src=loc s) = or(not(l), r, src=s);
Bool expand2(not(not(Bool b))) = b;
```

and then pass those or apply those: `(expand1 + expand2)(myBool)`

So to wrap this up:

- pattern matching is the key to macro expansion, patterns can be wrapped in functions or visit cases or both, and functions can be passed around and combined.
- watch out to do some "origin tracking" and forward `src` fields to the right-hand sides of rewrite rules, otherwise the generated code does not know where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the response, my usecase is closer to number 2. Basically I am building a DSL that transpiles to a dialect of SQL, on the high level I would like to use macros to handle the boilerplates and to create abstractions absent in SQL

Comment: ok that makes sense! I will adapt the answer. I have an example too.

Comment: Thanks @jurgen, I will be waiting on that sir.

Comment: already done :-)

Comment: Thanks sir, I would come back if I have further questions

Comment: I have started attempting to implement macro syntax and expansion with a simple entity language. I am trying to expand a for-loop inspired by (Crystal language)[https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.9/syntax_and_semantics/macros/index.html#variadic-arguments-and-splatting], even though I have something that works, what do advice I do to approach this?

Comment: I'd write a grammar for the macro definitions and macro usages. Then write a parse-tree-to-parse-tree transformation in Rascal. The parse tree of the usage of a macro will be substituted by its definition using a `visit` statement. Watch out for variable name clashes; typically the semantics of substitution are very much like beta reduction of the (typed) lambda calculus, but you also have to take care of "hygienic macros" for the local variables that may be in the bodies of the macro definition which could accidentally capture definitions on the outside of the macro call.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty name analysis would extract a relation from name definitions to locations from the parse tree first. You can also use `TypePal` for this for a more advanced name and type analysis that you can use to implement a type-safe macro subtitution.

Comment: Thanks @jurgen for the response, I tried the approach of implementing a simple type environment and it seems to work fine, but I soon realized the maybe I should just use `TypePal` to handle the type analysis instead. I will see how `TypePal` could be used instead. I will post questions if encounter any. ;-)

Comment: Hey @jurgen, I have not been able to get the `TypePal` to get the type-safe macro substitution to work, one of the reasons is because I don't really know where exactly `TypePal` sits in this process. Right now, at the point of the substitution, I just use simple if-then-else to do the checks but I know the `TypePal` solution will be neater.

Comment: @PiusArhanbhunde it's a matter of staging the stages :-) these stages: Parse->TypeAndNameAnalysis->MacroExpansion have to go somewhere into the rest of your pipeline. Are you running an interpreted lanuage, this would be part of your REPL, inside the "E". Is it a compiled language, you (probably) have this in your compiler pipeline already.

Comment: These are not the only options. It all depends on where and when you will bind the parameters to your macros and when you will expand them. Sometimes a type and name analysis can be correct for all possible instantiations of a macro, sometimes it is data-dependent. The more dynamic the bindings the later you have to wait with type-checking. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this really clears up some of my confusions, I will ping you when I get stuck or need more clarity @jurgen

Comment: Hey @jurgen, started trying my hands on the `TypeAndNameAnalysis`. While attempting it a few questions popped up in head. Firstly, does the analysis of the macros have to be separated from the analysis of the whole base language, I am thinking `Parse->TypeAndNameAnalysisforMacro->MacroExpansion->TypeAndNameAnalysis->Codegen`. Secondly, how will implementing late binding of the macro affect this pipeline if at all .

Comment: Hey @jurgen, during the implementation I figured out I should use a `Parse -> Analyze(with late binding for macros) -> Expand -> CodeGen`. Any advices on how to approach this with pointers to resources, Thanks.

Comment: @PiusArhanbhunde you are asking the right questions, but the answers are design decisions, not universal truths. What you choose will be what it is!

Comment: Thanks for the response @jurgen, I went ahead with the latter approach